# Django not sending email through gmail

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a online book store and I am trying to send an verification email to new signed users, but for some reason Email is not getting sent, I also tried to use app specific password in gmail.

A help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my Email code in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='kshitu.rangari@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='jgpcjiajvklxraof'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'books@pickabook.com'
```

Code in my Views.py

```
from .models import Book

def index (request):
    return render (request,'template.html')

def store (request):
    return render (request, 'store.html' )

def store (request):
    count = Book.objects.all().count()
    context = {
        'count':count,
    }
    return render (request,'store.html',context)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the stack trace of the error while sending the email?

Comment: That's the problem.. I am not getting any errors. When I hit register button, it goes to the page where it says "activation email has been sent", but not receiving any mail :(

Comment: Ok. Can you at least add the code where you trigger the Email. This will help one to debug the issue quickly

Comment: Honestly, I am very much new to python and django.. I am trying to follow a video tutorial.. in that tutorial the author does not add any email triggering code in views.py and his code still works, but else where on internet, I see there is email triggering code in views.

Comment: Even I was wondering about email triggering script.. any help regarding that will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering if Google is blocking your emails cause you're logged as `kshitu.rangari@gmail.com` but you're trying to send email as `books@pickabook.com`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already have the settings for email ready and to test whether emails are being sent, do the following

1. In settings.py make

`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
 DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER`

2. Run interactive mode,
   `python manage.py shell`
3. Import the EmailMessage module,
   `from django.core.mail import EmailMessage`
4. Send the email,

`email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', to=['kshitu.rangari@gmail.com'])
 email.send()`

If the above works successfully then your gmail account is configured to send emails.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kshit\Envs\bookstore-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 69, in handle
    self.run_shell(shell=options['interface'])
  File "C:\Users\kshit\Envs\bookstore-django\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\shell.py", line 61, in run_shell
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'EmailMessage' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: Its email.send(), it was a typo from my end later i edited

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_smtp_ssl'

Do I need to import any module ?

Comment: Then you need to change the EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'   in settings.py

Comment: Yes this worked. Thanks so much buddy..really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good to know. Cheers!

Comment: This works when I try to do it through command line..When I actually try it from register page..It does not :(

Comment: This is my activation.txt 

Greetings,


You Just signed up for an account at {{ site.name }},  Please click the link below to activate your account.

http://{site.domain}}{% url 'registration_activate' activation_key %}

This link is valid  for {{ expiration_days }} days. If it wasn't who signed up for this account, don't panic. Ignore this email.

- Pick A Book Team

Comment: TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 1):

For Gmail specifically, you might need to toggle the "enable less secure apps" function within your Google account.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Hi, I tried that too.. and also app specific passwords !!