# gmail is not sending from django web application

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I have created a Python-Django web application.
I tried to send an email to a user, but it is not working. How Can I solve it ?

```
#SMTP Configuration
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_POSRT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS =True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'fhcollege@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
```

This from my settings.py file

My views.py file is

```
email=EmailMessage(
            'PAYMENT SUCCESSFULL',
            'welcome',
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            ['fhcollege@google.com']
        )

        email.fail_silently = False
        email.send()
```

How can I solve the issue ?

The Error showing is

```
TimeoutError at /payments/4
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:9000/payments/4
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: TimeoutError
```

Comment: Check this link might help you solve. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42680703/16381386

Answer (score 0):

1. In settings.py make

`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER`

1. Import the EmailMessage module, `from django.core.mail import EmailMessage`
2. Send the email,`email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', to=['deneme.deneme@gmail.com']) email.send()`

**Specifically for Gmail, you may need to turn on "enable less secure apps" in your Google account..**

[Less secure apps & your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Comment: [Please only post in English here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/354577). If you prefer to use one of these languages, please do so on their dedicated sites: [es.so], [pt.so], [ru.so], [ja.so].

Comment: I tried this, But its not working